# cassandra dead but pid file exists on amzon centos6

Tags: linux, cassandra, centos

I am trying to install cassandra on amazon centOS6.0 for that i follow from [Caassandra](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-cassandra-on-centos-6/)

After successful install i am able to start the cassandra service but when trying to check status it throws "cassandra dead but pid file exists" error.

Any help.

Cassandra LOG:

```
 INFO 18:09:06,422 Logging initialized
 INFO 18:09:06,785 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 18:09:07,753 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 18:09:07,770 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO 18:09:07,771 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 18:09:07,771 disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 18:09:07,772 commit_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 18:09:07,799 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 72MB
 INFO 18:09:08,232 Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO 18:09:08,834 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 18:09:08,872 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 18:09:08,896 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_71
 INFO 18:09:08,896 Heap size: 301727744/302776320
 INFO 18:09:08,897 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 642560(627K) committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
 INFO 18:09:08,897 Eden Space Heap memory: init = 61341696(59904K) used = 46198280(45115K) committed = 61341696(59904K) max = 61341696(59904K)
 INFO 18:09:08,897 Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 7602176(7424K) used = 0(0K) committed = 7602176(7424K) max = 7602176(7424K)
 INFO 18:09:08,901 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 232783872(227328K) used = 0(0K) committed = 232783872(227328K) max = 233832448(228352K)
 INFO 18:09:08,902 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 13255544(12944K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 85983232(83968K)
 INFO 18:09:08,902 Classpath: /etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
```

System LOG:

```
INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:06,422 CassandraDaemon.java (line 141) Logging initialized
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:06,785 YamlConfigurationLoader.java (line 81) Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:07,753 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 143) Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:07,770 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 144) Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:07,771 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 184) DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:07,771 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 198) disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:07,772 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 199) commit_failure_policy is stop
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:07,799 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 269) Global memtable threshold is enabled at 72MB
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,232 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 410) Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,834 YamlConfigurationLoader.java (line 81) Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,872 YamlConfigurationLoader.java (line 81) Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,896 CassandraDaemon.java (line 217) JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_71
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,896 CassandraDaemon.java (line 245) Heap size: 301727744/302776320
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,897 CassandraDaemon.java (line 247) Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 642560(627K) committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,897 CassandraDaemon.java (line 247) Eden Space Heap memory: init = 61341696(59904K) used = 46198280(45115K) committed = 61341696(59904K) max = 61341696(59904K)
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,897 CassandraDaemon.java (line 247) Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 7602176(7424K) used = 0(0K) committed = 7602176(7424K) max = 7602176(7424K)
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,901 CassandraDaemon.java (line 247) CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 232783872(227328K) used = 0(0K) committed = 232783872(227328K) max = 233832448(228352K)
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,902 CassandraDaemon.java (line 247) CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 13255544(12944K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 85983232(83968K)
 INFO [main] 2016-02-16 18:09:08,902 CassandraDaemon.java (line 248) Classpath: /etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
```

When i type cassandra -f

```
[root@ip-10-147-234-46 ~]# cassandra -f
 INFO 18:31:32,468 Logging initialized
 INFO 18:31:32,828 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 18:31:33,727 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 18:31:33,738 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO 18:31:33,739 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 18:31:33,739 disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 18:31:33,739 commit_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 18:31:33,761 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 72MB
 INFO 18:31:34,150 Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO 18:31:34,749 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 18:31:34,787 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 18:31:34,809 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_71
 INFO 18:31:34,810 Heap size: 301727744/302776320
 INFO 18:31:34,811 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 642752(627K) committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
 INFO 18:31:34,811 Eden Space Heap memory: init = 61341696(59904K) used = 46225792(45142K) committed = 61341696(59904K) max = 61341696(59904K)
 INFO 18:31:34,811 Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 7602176(7424K) used = 0(0K) committed = 7602176(7424K) max = 7602176(7424K)
 INFO 18:31:34,815 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 232783872(227328K) used = 0(0K) committed = 232783872(227328K) max = 233832448(228352K)
 INFO 18:31:34,816 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 13255312(12944K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 85983232(83968K)
 INFO 18:31:34,816 Classpath: /etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.17.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
Killed
```

Comment: You can delete the lock ile from `/var/run/cassandra`, but before doin that check for error in cassandra log

Comment: Hi, I just edited question and added Cassandra log can you help me what causes issue.

Comment: Is it system.log? Look for ERROR in system.log

Comment: Added system LOG. I think both log looks similar

Comment: When i type cassandra -f it shows Killed at the end might be cause problem right?

Comment: Looks like the OS killed the process for some reason. Do you have sufficient RAM to run C* with those memory settings? Have you followed the [production settings guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html), in particular the part about user resource limits?

Comment: Hi, @Ralf Yes it was issue with instance that was created on amazon is very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue the day i asked this question.

The issue is on amazon instance that was configured for me was very small below the micro instance. So once i check the instance and update it to large instance issue goes away immediately. Any way thanks for other suggestion.